# How to get multiple 'publicTransportLine' in a Public Transportation route request?

Tags: rest, maps, here-api

I'm using this request: [Docs Example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-public-transport-routes.html)

But in all tests it just shows one bus line in 'publicTransportLine'. Is there any parameter to show more lines if available for the generated route?

My city is Londrina - Brazil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try adding "alternatives" parameter to the request (https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html)